# Связь переменной и строки

Tags: javascript, html, php

Есть строка для ввода текста, кнопка отправки, переменные:
$mail - на PHP
var mailjava -на Javascript
Как связать так, что бы при вводе текста он записывался как значение переменной хоть $mail, хоть mailjava - главное, чтобы записался и как сделать так, чтобы на e-mail a@bk.ru было отправлено письмо содержащее этот текст(переменная)

Comment: Это не вопрос, это набор слов. Объясни по человечески.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
    $mail = $_POST['text'];
    mail("a@bk.ru", "Заголовок", $mail);
}else{
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить"><br/>
    </form>
}
?>
```

Если я правильно понял, но при чем тут javascript?